# Runtime dynamic for object property

Tags: c#, dynamic

in order to determine my class type on Run-time i am using `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dynamic = new MyClass();
dynamic.SomeMethod();
```

So this work fine and all good, the problem is that if i want to reach this `object property` and in this case it seems that this is not possible:

```
dynamic.MyProperty;
```

> Error 1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new
>   object expressions can be used as a statement

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic.MyProperty;
```

Is not a statement you can't use it in this way. Instead you can do something like this:

```
 var abc = dynamic.MyProperty;
```